# How to create an ng Repeat block, based on an array defined in our controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This was not my initial question, but on the setup i came with this issue.

How can I List the type and value of vm.myItems ?

This is my code:

```js
  var app = angular.module('Appp', []);
        app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.vm = { myItems : {} }

            $scope.vm.myItems = [ {type: "a", value: 34.5},
                                  {type: "a", value: 12.5},
                                  {type: "b", value: 3.15} ];


        });
```

Comment: have you included `angularJs` ?

Comment: I just saw your edit. it's working fine. No  ?

Comment: yes, it was my fault. I +1 your comment because that was the solution. I'll eventually delete this question. Im using it to try to replicate my current issue

Comment: you can upvote and accept my answer too :p I need upvotes :D

Comment: @RagnaRock Did you edit the answer into your question? You shouldn't do that because it invalidates the answer.

Comment: Can you please brief out the problem? You only wanted to print elements on view using `ng-repeat`? If yes then did you check the docs

Comment: I did edited the question. I only wanted to list indeed. I forgot to add the angular script. It now solved

Comment: removed solution and edited solution to declare the answer. please don't amend the question to have the solution. Answer your question in an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the tags like so

```js
var app = angular.module('Appp', []);
        app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.vm = { myItems : {} }

            $scope.vm.myItems = [ {type: "a", value: 34.5},
                                  {type: "a", value: 12.5},
                                  {type: "b", value: 3.15} ];


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="Appp" name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl">
   
          <div ng-repeat="item in vm.myItems">
              {{item.type}} {{item.value}}
          </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Seems like it has similar content that OP has in its question..

Comment: @PankajParkar he edited his question when to what I answered

Comment: @PankajParkar I rolled it back.

Comment: @ModusTollens I'm afraid, was the problem only angularjs file reference was missing?

Comment: @PankajParkar I don't know. OP?